# SQLite: Finding the highest N values in a column, using a second column as a tiebreaker?

Tags: python, select, sqlite

Suppose Column 1 contains values `4, 6, 4, 1, 5` and Column 2 contains values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, corresponding to the values in Column 1, and I want the highest three values of column 1. How do I do this such that rows 2, 5, and 3 are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a composite `order by` clause with `limit` to get only the first 3:

```
select c1, c2
from  t
order by c1 desc, c2 desc
limit 3;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/38dd1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple levels ordering.

e.g 
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2 DESC LIMIT 3

sort by column1 first, if ties, use column2 to sort

[more information here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)